# ¿Cómo tener 2 proyectos Angular corriendo en un mismo equipo?

Tags: angular, servidor

Actualmente estoy trabajando con 2 proyectos en Angular (vista admin y vista usuario), cuando tengo que hacer cambios en una de las vistas tengo que cerrar el servidor de una vista para poder abrirla en otra. Quisiera saber si existe la forma de trabajar de manera simultanea estos dos proyectos sin cerrar el servidor de uno de ellos.

Lo que intenté hacer es colocar un puerto en el `angular.json` de uno de los proyectos:

```js
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "port": 8001
  },
 }
```

Pero esto no me funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el comando al iniciar tu app con el puerto que desees, por ejemplo el 4500 y le cambias el número cuando partas tu otra app

```
ng serve --port 4500 -o
```

y luego en la otra app

```
ng serve --port 4501 -o
```